# Passing ifstream object to a function that requires an istream type

Tags: c++, inheritance, ifstream, istream

I have this function

```
void StrType::saveString(bool skip, InType charsAllowed, std::istream& inStream)
{ //something cool 
};
```

and these two

```
void StrType::getString(bool skip, InType charsAllowed)
{
    saveString(skip, charsAllowed, std::cin);
}
void StrType::getStringFile(bool skip, InType charsAllowed,  std::ifstream& inFile)
{
    saveString(skip, charsAllowed, inFile);
}
```

Can you tell me why is the compilator complaining that

```
strtype.cpp: In member function ‘void StrType::getStringFile(bool, InType, std::ifstream&)’:
strtype.cpp:42:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘StrType::saveString(bool&, InType&, std::ifstream&)’
strtype.cpp:42:39: note: candidate is:
strtype.cpp:9:6: note: void StrType::saveString(bool, InType, std::istream&)
strtype.cpp:9:6: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}’ to ‘std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream<char>&}’
```

as the ifstream class inherits from istream? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: What compiler are you compiling with? This http://liveworkspace.org/code/b0876ae8193b301702e200d81b3a75f1 compiles on GCC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the most likely cause is a missing `<fstream>` header file. If all you have included is `<iosfwd>` then the compiler won't know that `ifstream` inherits from `istream`.

Comment: Dammit, you're right. I haven't just included the fstream header. So sad. Thanks